# Контроль заполнения строковых полей

Tags: python, строки, классы, методы

У меня есть класс "Книга" в котором нужно написать метод, контролирующий строковые поля. То есть при вводе он должен автоматически преобразовать строку к формату: первая буква большая, остальные маленькие. Пытался сделать с помощью метод control, но что-то не выходит.
Код метода:

```
    def __control(self, autor,name,pub):
            if self.__autor == autor:
                autor.title()
            if self.__name:
                name.title()
            if self.__pub:
                name.title()

            return autor, name, pub
      Book1 = Book("ПРОКОПЕНКО","ТУМАН", 24442,"СНЕГ",442,400)
print(Book1.getAutor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нужно делать в методе с именем `__init__()`:

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, autor, name, pub):
        self.autor = autor.title()
        self.name = name.title()
        self.pub = pub.title()

book1 = Book("ПРОКОПЕНКО", "ТУМАН", "СНЕГ")
print(book1.autor)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Прокопенко
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Carl, не стоит. Но когда был мой ответ для вас полезным, вы можете голосовать за него (клик на треугольник вверх у его начала) и / или принять его (клик на галочку).

Comment: так и сделал, но видимо из-за низкой репутации не засчиталось

Comment: @Carl, спасибо вам.

Comment: у меня появилась еще одна проблема, но я исчерпал лимит вопросов, могу ли я спросить здесь? или так не положено?

Comment: @Carl, попробуйте, но я теперь не буду здесь полчаса.

Comment: все же кое-как решил, поэтому снова спасибо за помощь и удачи